# How can I interactively change the shape of a cloth?

Tags: cloth-simulation, shape-keys

Below is a tutorial from Marvelous Designer to fold the tie into desired shape.

Is it possible to do it in blender?

[image]

Comment: Yes.  Blender has the curve modifier or bones to change/beform Mesh.  Bones have a Spline IK Constraint to follow a curve.  Mesh has shape keys.  So the animation is certainly possible.  Accuracy in Cloth Physics was not considered.  I am sure it will be a lot of fun for you to do, Blender always is.

Comment: Do you want to animate the tie being tied, or just end up with a model of a tie and add a cloth sim to it after it's modeled? (The latter will be much easier.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! @Mentalist: I need the former. My ultimate goal is to translate a "making tie" tutorial video into blender animation.

Comment: Blender is still on the way to develop a full workflow for cloth modelling, but some of the functionalities of marvelous designer have been implemented in the recently added cloth brush. You might want to [check out this post](https://code.blender.org/2020/10/cloth-sculpting-improvements-in-blender-2-91/) to see the updates.

Comment: This plugin is probably the most relevant to your needs at the moment, and it's still free.
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmPP5mdYOQI&ab_channel=RichColburn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmPP5mdYOQI&ab_channel=RichColburn)